# Extracting feature vectors from image in android app using MLKit

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, google-mlkit

Is there a possibility to use MLKit in an Android application in such a way that it only makes a feature vector from an image without any classification?

Is there any other way to extract feature vectors in Android app if it can't be done this way?

Comment: Cloud you classify what is the feature vector you mean? Are you using ML Kit Image labeling SDK?